# Can I install Ubuntu on my hard drive d without usb/cd?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, 22.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 but I don't have any USB or CD. And I have D hard drive to install Ubuntu. How can I install Ubuntu on that hard drive? I can't find a way to do it. Please help!!!

Comment: 1. It is possible but much more difficult to install Ubuntu without a separate drive for the installer. So I suggest that you borrow a USB drive from a friend or colleague for this purpose; 2. What do you mean by "D hard drive"? What computer is it (brand name and model)? What operating system is running now? Can you borrow or use another computer for this task? -- Please edit your original question with answers to these questions, it will help us help you.

Comment: The concept of "D disk" is a way Windows handles disks. Linux isn't Windows, and cannot use Windows "D disk". Shrink your D disk/Windiws partition so the disk has enough unallocated space to install Linux. 100GB should be enough. Be sure to turn off Windows "Fast boot" option - shutting down Windows with "Fast boot" enabled will make your Windows files inaccessible to Linux. Beware: Some Windows updates re-enable "Fast boot".